# How to draw labels in the Y axis with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart library in my android app to show a price chart. The requirement is to show a label with the max and min price as shown in the picture below. Any idea about how can I do that with the library? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: do you want show label right top and right bottom of the chart?

Comment: @sasikumar yes. I know I can wrap the chart within a view group and add the labels myself but I wonder if the library already has something to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the below solution :D

```
private fun showPriceLimits(lp: Float, hp: Float) {
    val highestPrice = LimitLine(hp, hp.toString())
    highestPrice.lineColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, color.transparent)
    highestPrice.textSize = 13f

    val lowestPrice = LimitLine(lp, lp.toString())
    lowestPrice.lineColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, color.transparent)
    lowestPrice.textSize = 13f

    chart.axisRight.addLimitLine(highestPrice)
    chart.axisRight.addLimitLine(lowestPrice)
  }
```